# why data should be copied or cloned before pushing in linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

My question is about passing  address to push function of linked list , so why pushing data address is not enough in this code, why data should be copied first by `new int (i)` what happen in the memory when the address only used:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

struct holder
{
    struct node
    {
        node* next ;
        void* value ;
    }*top;
    void initialize() ;
    void *pop();
    void push(void*val) ;
};

void holder::initialize()
{
    top = 0 ;
}
void holder::push(void*val)
{
    node* newnode = new node;
    newnode->value = val ;
    newnode->next = top ;
    top = newnode ;
}

void* holder::pop()
{
    void* result ;
    node* oldtop ;
    result = top->value ;
    oldtop = top ;
    top = top->next ;
    delete oldtop ;
    return result ;
}

int main()
{
    holder test ;
    test.initialize() ;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <10 ; i++)
    {
        // test.push (&i) ;   not working
        test.push(new int (i)) ;
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i <10 ; i++)
    {
        cout << *(int*)test.pop() << endl ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "not working" code, you are pushing the same pointer every time &i doesn't change as i does.  So you will have 10 copies of the same pointer to that local variable.  The list only contains pointers to values, so you need to allocate memory to actually place the values as well.

Also, after you retrieve the pointer back out of the stack, you need to delete the allocated memory.  Something like this:

```
int *value = (int*)test.pop();
cout << *value << endl ;
delete value;
```

In that context, the need for new may be more obvious.

Comment: Also, when the `for` loop ends and `i` is no longer in scope, the list will be pointing to memory that could be then used for something else (and the 'values' stored in the list be changed by unrelated code).

Comment: but why '&i' is not refreshed in each time by the new value of i , while in this code the output is 10 (10 times) instead of 0 the initial value of i

Comment: The quantity stored by the holder structure is the memory address of the variable i, not the value contained in i.  The location of i in memory doesn't change, so the same value is put in each time.  When it comes time to print the value out, the computer goes off to that address, and prints whatever is in that address at the time.  Given that i is actually now out of scope (as it was defined within the for loop), by luck that memory hasn't been changed by anything else and you get 10, the last value it was assigned with.

Answer (score 1):

```
test.push (&i)
```

Pushes the address of `i`, which never changes, 10x.

```
test.push(new int (i)) ;
```

Creates a new, unique variable 10x and pushes the unique address into the list.

You might consider using [templates rather than void pointers.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa296596%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)